# MiXCR: only create a single export file for all clonotypes

Tags: sequence-alignment, fasta, bash

I am using following command from MiXCR to both align, assemble and export my input files:

```
mixcr analyze amplicon \
    -s hsa \
    --starting-material rna \
    --5-end no-v-primers \
    --3-end c-primers \
    --adapters adapters-present \
    --export "-aaFeature CDR1 -nFeature CDR1 -aaFeature CDR2 \
              -nFeature CDR2 -aaFeature CDR3 -nFeature CDR3 \
              -aaFeature VGene -cGenes -count" \
    --assemble "-OassemblingFeatures=[CDR1,CDR2,CDR3]" \
    INPUT_FILE.fasta analysis_name
```

Unfortunately, this creates multiple output file (analysis_name.clonotypes.ALL.txt, analysis_name.clonotypes.IGH.txt, etc.), which stands in contrast to the output of the `mixcr exportAlignments` command.

How can I export a single txt file instead, while still using the `mixcr analyze` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from the [MiXCR documentation](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/mixcr/develop/mixcr.pdf):

```
Under the hood analyze amplicon is equivalent to the execution of the following
MiXCR actions options:
> mixcr align -s hs -p kAligner2 input_R1.fastq input_R2.fastq alignments.vdjca
... Building alignments
> mixcr assemble alignments.vdjca clones.clns
... Assembling clones
> mixcr exportClones --chains IGH clones.clns clones.txt
... Exporting clones to tab-delimited file
```

So when using `analyze amplicon`, you are using `mixcr exportClones` under the hood and not `exportAlignments`, hence the difference in output.

I believe what you are experiencing results from a bug, please see this [issue](https://github.com/milaboratory/mixcr/issues/454). If this is the case, all these files should be the same according to the bug report. Fortunately the developers have already addressed the bug in version 3.0.3.

Comment: As I was already running version 3.0.9 of mixcr, the bug you found (which corresponds to my observation) should have been fixed. However, although running `mixcr exportClones prefix.clna clones.txt` returns only one file as expected, the same is not true for me when using the `analyze amplicon` command. So, even though those commands are supposed to be equivalent, their output suggests otherwise for me.

Answer (score 3):

Currently in MiXCR SERIES 4 you can use `--dont-split-files`  parameter here.
Please check our new documentation portal:
https://docs.milaboratories.com/mixcr/reference/mixcr-export/#clonotype-tables

Also now we support presets that allow to perform analysis for a lot of standard protocols using a one line command.

Answer (score 2):

After finding the correct entry in the MiXCR documentation (thanks to haci), I learned that the parameter `--receptor-type` is responsible for which sequences will be returned.

The default for this parameter when using mixcr analyze is `--receptor-type xcr`, and stands for 'all chains', thus returning such a vast output. Changing this parameter to e.g. BCR solved my issue.

Comment: Where can I find the default value for the --receptor-type parameter? I cannot find it in the manual, can you please point out the relevant section?

Comment: I found it in the analyze section of the [MiXCR docs](https://mixcr.readthedocs.io/en/master/analyze.html), under the optional parameters.